# how to pass integer in yaml through csv file in artillery load testing

Tags: node.js, csv, yaml, load-testing

I am using post request With JSON Object:

```
{
     "name": "Emmy",
     "age": 11,
     "state": "Goa",
     "country": "india"
}
```

my CSV file is :

```
name,age,state,country
Emmy,11,Goa,india
```

and my artilery code :

```
config:
  target: 'http://localhost:5000'
  phases:
    - duration: 60
      arrivalRate: 10
  defaults:
    headers:
      token: 'TOKEN'
  payload:
    path: "./hello.csv"
    fields:
      - "name"
      - "age"
      - "state"
      - "country"
scenarios:
  - flow:    
    - post:
        url: "url"
        json:
         name: "{{name}}" 
         age: "{{age}}"
         state: "{{state}}"
         country: "{{country}}"
```

I have validation for each field in which `age` will take only integer values but artillery is taking `string` values so i an getting validation error. how to pass age as `integer` in yaml file.

Comment: Have you tried `{{age}}` without `"` ?

Comment: yes it is giving syntax error of yaml @Gabriel Bleu

Answer (score 1):

If you don't find any other solution, you can run custom code :

```
function setJSONBody(requestParams, context, ee, next) {
  return next(); // MUST be called for the scenario to continue
}
```

doc : https://artillery.io/docs/http-reference/#advanced-writing-custom-logic-in-javascript

Comment: as i tried using hardcoding , its working but i wanted it to be through csv file because i have created my module in that way

Comment: You can use your CSV and only cast age in this script.

Comment: Yeah I am using temporarily same but that is not my solution.

Comment: Seems to be the only solution though : https://github.com/shoreditch-ops/artillery/issues/250

Answer (score 1):

To explicitly load a string enclosed in quotes as an integer in YAML, you need to add the `!!int` tag:

```
---
integer: !!int "{{ variable }}"
```

It is needed in this case, because a plain scalar cannot start with `{` as this is starting a flow style mapping.

However, this won't work if the substitution of the `{{ var }}` happens *after* loading and resolving the tag, because then it would try to resolve the verbatim string `{{ var }}` as an integer which will fail.

Here's an article about Tags/Schemas/Types in YAML 1.1 and 1.2 I wrote in December which might help understanding:
[Introduction to YAML Schemas and Tags](http://blogs.perl.org/users/tinita/2018/01/introduction-to-yaml-schemas-and-tags.html)